# How to use Automatic Lip Sync in Blender 2D with Papagayo?

Tags: animation

LipSyn addon: https://github.com/iCEE-HAM/io_import_lipSync-blender2.8

Papagayo: https://my.smithmicro.com/papagayo.html

**1) Record your voice using Papagayo. Make adjustments and export as *.dat file.**

**2) Open Blender. Select EDIT, PREFERENCES, ADDONS. Click INSTALL and choose the downloaded file above.**

**3) Go to main 3D viewport. Press 'N' to open the sidebar tab on the right.
Choose the 'ANIMATION' tab and import your Papagayo file (*.dat)**

**4) *Please help complete this guide**

What's next? Shape keys?  Poses? Vertex Groups? UV wrapping with bone layers?
I'm familiar with lip sync from other animation programs, but new to Blender I have mouth phonemes and assume I need to make a new POSE for each sound/mouth shape, but I'm not sure how to begin. I have tried these tutorials below but nothing is complete.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m8UEazfJxoo&lc=UgywuTIaW-SKmG9hF_h4AaABAg.98urW4ssERX98vZE02FEwO

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tCxKbaUKbg0

Comment: Did you watch _"Tutorial I recomand for making the shapekeys and importing the .dat files https://youtu.be/OV45cE7pl3o "_  from addon link?

Comment: Yes, but when I reach 44:15 the clip jumps straight to 'shape keys'. I don't have a character built. Every tutorial jumps to shape keys, vertex groups or poses with no explanation how to create them. I am missing that step for some reason.

Comment: Hi, welcome! So, maybe your question should ask "how to create shape keys, vertex groups or poses" perhaps...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not 100% sure what my question should be. I could ask about shape keys, and be completely wrong. Shape keys were one of a few guesses. When people search "How to lip sync in Blender using Papagayo" it would be VERY beneficial to have a walkthrough guide, step by step, start to finish. Instead of having information segregated. I understand the advantage of asking a specific question, but I don't think its helpful in this scenario.

Comment: IIRC (the bat3a addon) you set up shapekeys with phoneme names first. The animation creates keyframes to animate these.

Comment: Tutorial for making the shapekeys and importing the .dat files https://youtu.be/OV45cE7pl3o